# CSS Background Slideshow too Slow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I am trying to build my website, I am new at this and all but I have tried to use this code for a background slideshow and unfortunately, it takes forever to load the page. I have optimized the 3-500KB images to now 90-100KB and still takes forever for some to load... Help!

[My updated version of my site](http://globalplayernetwork.com/in.html). I am trying to make it load quicker with these tips I found on the net but I am having a horrible time making it load quick enough.

- [My CSS File](http://globalplayernetwork.com/css/style.css) (too large to post).
- [My HTML Page](http://pastebin.com/wHvPwKby) can't be posted here, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: WHOA! : Inspecting globalplayernetwork.com/in.html showed it loaded 10.2MB

Comment: How can I make it less? I don't understand... How/why that is... I use the PageSpeed Insight from Google and it gives me a 96/100 but it still loads slow for some :(.

Comment: Use Lazy Loading. Your images are causing the delay : 
http://globalplayernetwork.com/images/album/gpnSW.png, ...

Comment: Pranav: On the new page I am trying to fix it currently loads just 90 and 91.jpg (http://globalplayernetwork.com/images/album/90.jpg). Does this still apply as they're smaller?

Answer (score 1):

On Inspection, it seems that the images you are loading are way too many, and at once, which makes the site slow.

[image]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPRxM.png)

You should use Lazy Loading to achieve loading the site faster, since, this way only the required images get loaded.

Request the images when they are required (Or probably a little before they are required), but you should definitely **NOT** get all requests together.

Secondly, you should have different image sizes, ready, as required, not making the browser to  resize the images. It consumes both time and processing to get images to resize, by the browser. It would make life simpler if you had copies of images.

There are a lot of plugins available to achieve Lazy Loading.
Since you are using jQuery, here are a few :

1. http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload (Simple Demo [Here](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html))
2. http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/lazy-loading-images/
3. http://www.google.com/search?q=lazy+loading+jquery

Other Tips :

Combine all your scripts to one, and make one single `js` file.

So, the following :

```
 - <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pop-ups.js"></script>
 - <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script> 
 - <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script> 
 - <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.jscrollpane.min.js"></script> 
 - <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon.js"></script>
```

becomes `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/all.js"></script>`

Now, to further optimize, minify them.

There are a lot of online tools, but I love [this](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) one.

Also, I'd advise you to have a look at [this](http://speakerdeck.com/player/87fa761026bf013092b722000a1d8877#), (check slide 97 onwards), a presentation by Chris Coyier.

Answer (score 0):

@Pranav's answer is pretty good.

You should definitely take a look at all the tools that chrome inspector has (I'm sure firefox)

Loading your site gives me 94 errors.

You need to take a look at a lot of things but I would definitely recommend using css sprites, specially for that insane amount of pictures.

You **need to minimize the requests**. Take a look at what I'm talking about [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

---

Here is what chrome audit is telling about your site, you don't need to do all of this but you should try to do:

```
Combine external JavaScript (16)
There are multiple resources served from same domain. Consider combining them into as few files as possible.
8 JavaScript resources served from globalplayernetwork.com.
5 JavaScript resources served from maps.gstatic.com.
3 JavaScript resources served from maps.google.com.
Enable gzip compression (20)
Compressing the following resources with gzip could reduce their transfer size by about two thirds (~668.95KB):
in.html could save ~10.15KB
style.css could save ~12.02KB
jquery.min.js could save ~46.99KB
pop-ups.js could save ~4.91KB
jquery.easing.1.3.js could save ~3.54KB
jquery.mousewheel.js could save ~881B
jquery.jscrollpane.min.js could save ~9.52KB
cufon.js could save ~14.03KB
Quicksand_Book_400.font.js could save ~17.13KB
functions.js could save ~2.10KB
jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js could save ~8.67KB
%7Bmain,mod_util,mod_act,mod_act_s,mod_actbr,mod_adf,mod_appiw,mod_gmmp,mod_mg,mod_mssvt,mod_pphover,mod_rst,mod_strr%7D.js could save ~354.18KB
click could save ~343B
main.js could save ~103.37KB
hosts.js could save ~8.07KB
%7Bmod_ctrapp,mod_touch,mod_rot,mod_exdom,mod_kbrd,mod_lyrs,mod_blyr,mod_qdt,mod_trtlr%7D.js could save ~57.23KB
mod_svau.js could save ~2.14KB
%7Bmod_tfcapp,mod_lyctr%7D.js could save ~12.15KB
maps.google.com/cbk?output=xml&hl=en&ll=36.131931,-115.160451&cb_client=&v=4 could save ~659B
mod_ls.js could save ~926B
Leverage browser caching (120)
The following resources specify a "Vary" header that disables caching in most versions of Internet Explorer:
icon_mhlasvegasdowntownbj.png
The following resources are explicitly non-cacheable. Consider making them cacheable if possible:
in.html
style.css
90.jpg
GPNLogo.png
1joe.jpg
5.jpg
thestrip.jpg
gpn13.jpg
gpnSStrip.jpg
gpn3.jpg
10.jpg
gpn11.jpg
gpn9.jpg
gpn4.jpg
gpnSW.jpg
close.png
200x200.png
CritterPokerIcon.jpg
p48_baccarat_comp.jpg
roulette_icon.png
street-craps-icon.png
slide4.png
maps
facebook.png
linkedin.png
twitter.png
jquery.min.js
pop-ups.js
jquery.easing.1.3.js
jquery.mousewheel.js
jquery.jscrollpane.min.js
cufon.js
Quicksand_Book_400.font.js
functions.js
jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js
home3.html
v=123&src=app&x=2950&y=6425&z=14&s=Gal
v=123&src=app&x=2951&y=6425&z=14&s=Galile
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2950&y=6425&z=14&s=Gal
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2951&y=6425&z=14&s=Galile
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2950&y=6426&z=14&s=Gali
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2951&y=6426&z=14&s=Galileo
transparent.png
%7Bmain,mod_util,mod_act,mod_act_s,mod_actbr,mod_adf,mod_appiw,mod_gmmp,mod_mg,mod_mssvt,mod_pphover,mod_rst,mod_strr%7D.js
90.jpg
91.jpg
overlay.png
down.png
up.png
main.js
hosts.js
pt
vp
%7Bmod_ctrapp,mod_touch,mod_rot,mod_exdom,mod_kbrd,mod_lyrs,mod_blyr,mod_qdt,mod_trtlr%7D.js
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2950&y=6427&z=14&s=Galil
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2951&y=6427&z=14&s=
transparent.png
red_markers_A_J2.png
shadow50.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
lyrs=h@202219229&hl=en&src=api&x=2950&y=6426&z=14&s=Gali
lyrs=h@202208787&hl=en&src=api&x=2951&y=6426&z=14&s=Galileo
lyrs=h@202220091&hl=en&src=api&x=2950&y=6425&z=14&s=Gal
lyrs=h@202153576&hl=en&src=api&x=2951&y=6425&z=14&s=Galile
red_markers_A_J2.png
shadow50.png
markerTransparent.png
dithshadow.gif
mod_svau.js
%7Bmod_tfcapp,mod_lyctr%7D.js
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2952&y=6426&z=14&s=Ga
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2952&y=6425&z=14&s=G
iw3.png
iws3.png
transparent.png
red_grow_markers_A_J2.png
shadow50.png
transparent.png
markerTransparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
maps.google.com/cbk?output=xml&hl=en&ll=36.131931,-115.160451&cb_client=&v=4
red_grow_markers_A_J2.png
transparent.png
shadow50.png
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2952&y=6427&z=14&s=Gal
v=123&src=app&x=2950&y=6427&z=14&s=Galil
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
v=123&src=app&x=2951&y=6427&z=14&s=
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
v=123&src=app&x=2952&y=6426&z=14&s=Ga
v=123&src=app&x=2952&y=6425&z=14&s=G
v=123&src=app&x=2952&y=6427&z=14&s=Gal
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
lyrs=h@202214362&hl=en&src=api&x=2950&y=6427&z=14&s=Galil
lyrs=h@202216272&hl=en&src=api&x=2951&y=6427&z=14&s=
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
lyrs=h@202208787&hl=en&src=api&x=2952&y=6426&z=14&s=Ga
lyrs=h@202179311&hl=en&src=api&x=2952&y=6425&z=14&s=G
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
lyrs=h@202219273&hl=en&src=api&x=2952&y=6427&z=14&s=Gal
mod_ls.js
Leverage proxy caching (5)
The following publicly cacheable resources contain a Set-Cookie header. This security vulnerability can cause cookies to be shared by multiple users.
icon_mhlasvegasdowntownbj.png
480_icon.png
v=123&src=app&x=2950&y=6426&z=14&s=Gali
v=123&src=app&x=2951&y=6426&z=14&s=Galileo
cbk
Minimize cookie size
The average cookie size for all requests on this page is 99B
Parallelize downloads across hostnames (51)
This page makes 51 parallelizable requests to maps.gstatic.com. Increase download parallelization by distributing the following requests across multiple hostnames.
back_gray.png
smc.png
poweredby.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
emulate_iphone_full2.png
iw2.png
transparent.png
red_markers_A_J2.png
shadow50.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
mp4.png
hpimgs28.png
red_markers_A_J2.png
shadow50.png
markerTransparent.png
dithshadow.gif
iw3.png
iws3.png
transparent.png
red_grow_markers_A_J2.png
shadow50.png
transparent.png
markerTransparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
red_grow_markers_A_J2.png
transparent.png
shadow50.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
transparent.png
Serve static content from a cookieless domain (32)
29.32KB of cookies were sent with the following static resources. Serve these static resources from a domain that does not set cookies:
icon_mhlasvegasdowntownbj.png
p48_baccarat_comp.jpg
p
transparent.png
v=123&src=app&x=2950&y=6425&z=14&s=Gal
v=123&src=app&x=2950&y=6426&z=14&s=Gali
v=123&src=app&x=2950&y=6427&z=14&s=Galil
v=123&src=app&x=2952&y=6426&z=14&s=Ga
v=123&src=app&x=2952&y=6425&z=14&s=G
v=123&src=app&x=2952&y=6427&z=14&s=Gal
v=123&src=app&x=2951&y=6425&z=14&s=Galile
v=123&src=app&x=2951&y=6426&z=14&s=Galileo
v=123&src=app&x=2951&y=6427&z=14&s=
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2950&y=6425&z=14&s=Gal
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2950&y=6426&z=14&s=Gali
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2950&y=6427&z=14&s=Galil
lyrs=h@202219229&hl=en&src=api&x=2950&y=6426&z=14&s=Gali
lyrs=h@202220091&hl=en&src=api&x=2950&y=6425&z=14&s=Gal
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2952&y=6426&z=14&s=Ga
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2952&y=6425&z=14&s=G
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2952&y=6427&z=14&s=Gal
lyrs=h@202214362&hl=en&src=api&x=2950&y=6427&z=14&s=Galil
lyrs=h@202208787&hl=en&src=api&x=2952&y=6426&z=14&s=Ga
lyrs=h@202179311&hl=en&src=api&x=2952&y=6425&z=14&s=G
lyrs=h@202219273&hl=en&src=api&x=2952&y=6427&z=14&s=Gal
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2951&y=6425&z=14&s=Galile
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2951&y=6426&z=14&s=Galileo
lyrs=h@202000000&hl=en&src=api&x=2951&y=6427&z=14&s=
lyrs=h@202208787&hl=en&src=api&x=2951&y=6426&z=14&s=Galileo
lyrs=h@202153576&hl=en&src=api&x=2951&y=6425&z=14&s=Galile
lyrs=h@202216272&hl=en&src=api&x=2951&y=6427&z=14&s=
cbk
Specify image dimensions (16)
A width and height should be specified for all images in order to speed up page display. The following image(s) are missing a width and/or height:
1joe.jpg
5.jpg
thestrip.jpg
gpn13.jpg
gpnSStrip.jpg
gpn3.jpg
10.jpg
gpn11.jpg
gpn9.jpg
gpn4.jpg
gpnSW.jpg
close.png (4 uses)
200x200.png
facebook.png
linkedin.png
twitter.png
Web Page Performance
Optimize the order of styles and scripts (1)
The following external CSS files were included after an external JavaScript file in the document head. To ensure CSS files are downloaded in parallel, always include external CSS before external JavaScript.
1 inline script block was found in the head between an external CSS file and another resource. To allow parallel downloading, move the inline script before the external CSS file, or after the next resource.
Remove unused CSS rules (2287)
93.85KB (80%) of CSS is not used by the current page.
style.css: 5.24KB (37%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #1: 222B (31%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #2: 0B (0%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #3: 54.91KB (90%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #4: 20.84KB (72%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #5: 4.16KB (93%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #6: 908B (100%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #7: 723B (100%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #8: 1.37KB (100%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #9: 96B (100%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #10: 2.14KB (83%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #11: 2.00KB (100%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #12: 636B (93%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #13: 267B (100%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #14: 269B (100%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #15: 149B (100%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #16: 0B (0%) is not used by the current page.
Inline block #17: 0B (0%) is not used by the current page.
```